# How to check if the user registration is allowed/active?

Tags: user-registration

I need to run a code snippet if the user registration is allowed, but I can't find a solution. How to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question completely. If it's your own website then you can check it yourself from `wp-admin` and if you are trying to spam other's website then I think this is not the right place to ask such question.

Comment: @robert-hue I am not a hacker :)! I need to display programmatically a message when the registration is enabled.

Comment: My apologies. I thought you are asking about 3rd party websites. I posted an answer to your question. Please check.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check it very easily with the help of [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

Here is a simple code for checking if user registration is allowed.

```
if ( get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) {

    // Your custom code or message to display if user registration is allowed.

}
```

`get_option( 'users_can_register' )` returns boolean true (1) or false (0).